# Issue with images uploaded via phone being wrong orientation on front-end

Tags: php, ios, image

To keep it brief, I have a website where my community can upload images and then those images (once approved), are displayed for all of the community to view.

When images are uploaded on a Computer, the orientation is correct on both Computer/Mobile devices.

When images are uploaded via Phone, the orientation is correct when viewing my website on a phone, but on the computer all of those images uploaded via phone are rotated 90 degrees.

I use Amazon for hosting, and when I right click and view the image I see it was indeed uploaded correctly.  For some reason the orientation is just messed up for PC users.  Does anyone have ideas on what I might need to add to correct this issue?  I am using PHP for the back-end.

Example of Image uploaded via phone: https://s3.amazonaws.com/prosp-test/quests/images/quest-12/25.png

On computer when viewing website, image displays like: http://s1.postimg.org/3l2i7841b/orientation.png

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to take the EXIF data in the image and rotate it accordingly. The very helpful library Intervention has a function for doing this (http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate) or you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php to do it yourself (see the comments on that page for examples).

Comment: This should the accepted answer :)